# F# three parameter infix operator

Tags: f#, operators

How to use a three parametered infix operator?

Eg.: base function is
`let orElse labelFunc p1 p2 = {...}` and operator `let ( <|> ) = orElse`

Now, for non-infix version this works nicely:`List.reduce ((<|>) labelFunc) parserList`.

Can I use it somehow still "infixing"? eg.: `(p1 (<|> labelFunc) p1)` does not work nor any other combination, other than using the non-infix version here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I think it's best to restrict the number of custom operators you're using in your code, because custom operators make F# code hard to read. F# lets you define custom operators, but it's not particularly designed to make this a great experience - it makes sense for some small domain-specific languages (like parser combinators), but not much else.

So, while I do not recommend using this, there is a weird trick that you can use to write something like `p1 (<op> l) p2`, which is to make `<op>` infix and replace the parentheses with two more custom operators:

```
let (</) a b = a, b
let (/>) c d = c, d
let (!) f = f

1 </ !10 /> 2
```

This sample just produces a tuple with all three arguments, but if you implement your logic in the `</` operator, it will actually do something like what you want. But as I said, I would not do this :-).

Comment: Tomas, how does something like FSharp.Interop.Dynamic provide an infix operator like `let (?<-) (target : obj) (name : string) (value : 'TValue) : unit = target |> Dyn.set name value` that gets called like `tgt?Prop<-"value"`?

Comment: The `?` and `?<-` operators are treated in a special way by F# - there is no way you can get this behaviour for your own custom operators.

Comment: That makes sense, though I really dislike 'special' when it comes to languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any good way to achieve that.  Once you have a parenthesized expression it won't be parsed as an operator - even `1 (+) 1` doesn't work.